# Is `printf %s` an identity operation or could it change a string

Tags: bash, printf

Is `printf %s "$string"` an identity operation, i.e. does `string="$( printf %s "$string" )"` change `$string` (except for the removal of trailing newlines that `$( )` does)?

Comment: `$(...)` runs in a subshell, that use a copy of all vars of the base shell and prints a string as result. Then the base shell catches the output and stores the result in its var `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> could it [`printf %s`] change a string

No, `printf %s` can only print a string, it cannot change a value of a variable.

> does string="$( printf %s "$string" )" change $string (except for the removal of trailing newlines that $( ) does)?

The line `string="$( printf %s "$string" )"` removes trailing newlines from `string` and does not change it otherwise.